# Color will not change when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to implement a feature on a menu that i am working on.When i scroll more than 50 pixels, let's say, i want to make the background color black, for example. Here is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("test");
   if ( document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50 ) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
   }
  }
```

```css
#test {
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  height: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.change { 
   background-color: black;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onscroll="myFunction()">
  <div id="test">
    <p>
      Wow, this is some really nice text, now isn't it?
    </p>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <div id="demo">
    Kachow, another text.
  </div>
</body>
```

As you can see, the background colour won't change. If you look at the CSS rules, you can see that the extra colour is added, but crossed off (in FireFox). Would you know why?

**JSFiddle Demo:**  https://jsfiddle.net/TakeDown/7djmqkzL/12/.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id selector has a higher specificity than a plain class selector. Meaning your class css won't override the id one. So you need to create a selector that has a higher specificity, and in your case just tag on the id selector:

```
#test.change {
  background-color:black;
}
```

If you don't want to tie it to a particular id, you can tag on the element name instead to make the specificity higher

```
div.change {
  background-color:black
}
```

[Can read more about css selector specificity on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) or [in the spec at here](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity)

Demo

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("test");
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    x.classList.add("change");
  } else {
    x.classList.remove("change");
  }
}
```

```css
#test {
  background-color: #d2d2d2;
  height: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#test.change {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onscroll="myFunction()">
  <div id="test">
    <p>
      Wow, this is some really nice text, now isn't it?
    </p>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <div id="demo">
    Kachow, another text.
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked. But i see there are some graphical glitches between scrolls. would you know why? on my menu i have set up an `if` so that it removes the class when the scroll is under a specified pixel and i got rid of some other bugs, but can't figure this one out.

Comment: Just change the `toggle()` to `add()` instead, ie `x.classList.add('change')`. And if you want it removed just use `x.classList.remove('change')` in an else block.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of graphical glitches don't use toggle

```
x.classList.toggle("change");
```

Instead, just set it to black when the scroll is 50

```
x.style.background = "black";
```

Comment: i see, but how would i go around if i have the color set with rgba. i am using it for the alpha value.

Comment: so if you are using it just for the alpha value, you can just set its opacity instead of setting its color

Comment: then the whole div will dissapear. or do you mean, i can set the opacity of the color in a similar fashion? i didn't know about such wizardry

Comment: yes, try doing  `x.style.opacity = "0.5"`. I'm not sure what you mean by setting the opacity of the color, but hopefully this is what you are aiming for

Comment: @hoobit, when using rgba the a stands for alpha (opacity) so like your 0.5 example would be `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`. Setting the actual opacity style will make the entire div see through, which could hurt readability

Comment: rgba colors are like this rgba(x, y, z, opacity). 0 opacity is like background-color: transparent and 1 is the full color in all its glory

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry i misunderstood. maybe set color like this `x.style.background= "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"`